# Issue with Rocksmith cable after upgrade to OSX Mavericks

Tags: technical-issues, macos, rocksmith-2014, mavericks

I recently upgraded my version of OSX to Mavericks, and since this change my computer has not been able to detect when I plug my guitar into the computer.  I had no issue previously in Lion, however now I cannot seem to get it to work.

When I plug it in, I don't see any indication that it is available in my available devices...its as if the connection does not exist.

Does anybody have a solution for this problem?

Comment: I too am noticing this issue.

Comment: I can mention that I upgraded from Mountain Lion about a month ago. And I haven't had any problems with Rocksmith or the cable (touch wood). Time Machine is another story though. :/